C# How is variable type nullable when assigned with null-coalescing operator and throwing if null
I have a nullable dictionary type which in turn can then have nullable values, however I am using the null-coalescing operator to throw an exception and break execution of the code if the expression ever evaluates to a null value.
How then is my variable type still being evaluated to a nullable string?


And what happens if you don't use var? string groupId = ...

Similar! But this is in particular using the null-coalescing operator and throwing if null

@gunr2171 yes it works if I use string to defined the variable type, however the question is why Visual Studio is misintepreting the possible results in the first place. The expression is interprested as nullable, when there is not a possible null result

It's not a Visual Studio thing, nor does it have anything to do with the null coalescing operator or the throw. It's simply because you're using var.  https://i.sstatic.net/f5tT8D26.png

So it's not actually possible to have a non-nullable typed reference variable if you are using var?
